# hoverintent with a separate overlay

Tags: jquery, html, timer, hover, hoverintent

[link on codepen](http://codepen.io/jonnowitts/pen/skgAF)

Hey,

Having some issues with hoverIntent.

When the user hovers the list item, I want two things to happen:
1. The div within that particular li will appear (on a delay to prevent accidental hover triggering).
2. A background overlay will cover the page - much like a light box. This will focus the attention on the list and visible div.

```
<header>
  <ul class="bars">
  <li><a href="#">Leeds bar</a>
      <div class="mega-menu-wrapper">
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">London bar</a>
      <div class="mega-menu-wrapper">
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">York bar</a>
      <div class="mega-menu-wrapper">
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Manchester bar</a>
      <div class="mega-menu-wrapper">
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</header>
<div id="mega-menu-overlay"></div>


$(function(){
        var $menuOverlay = $('#mega-menu-overlay');
        $('header .bars').hoverIntent(function() {
        // Check to see if a timer was set
            var timer = $(this).data('timer');
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }

            $(".mega-menu-wrapper", this).addClass('active');
      $menuOverlay.addClass('active');
        }, function(){
            var li = $(".mega-menu-wrapper",this);

            // Set a timer to remove the active class
            li.data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
                li.removeClass('active');
                $menuOverlay.removeClass('active');
            }, 100));               
        }, 'li');
    });
```

At the moment the overlay flickers between list item hovers, I've identified this is down to the hoverIntent being set per li, so each time it adds and removes the active class.

My solution would be:
- On remove hover
 - Start a 500ms timer
 - while the timer is running, has an

been rehovered?
   - yes, keep the active class on the overlay
   - no, remove the active class on the overlay

I can't figure out how to do this though, can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: added, also there was a link to it working in codepen.

Comment: What si the problem i dont understand it

Comment: In short: I want to stop the flicker of the overlay when switching between list items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: your clear interval didn'r work.
i made a own mouseenter that clears the interval as long as you are on the element

```
  $('header .bars').mouseover(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer); 
  });
```

and another timer function:

```
    timer = setTimeout(function() {

        li.removeClass('active');
        $menuOverlay.removeClass('active');
    }, 1500);
```

here a link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CHLsi

Comment: Thanks. The overlay works, but when hovering to a different item, the other does not disappear (as with the original pen).

Comment: thats becouse the timeout was set to 1500 set it back to 100 and it works

Comment: Still not having any luck I'm afraid.

Comment: i edited the plugin code for you, now it works ( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CHLsi )